# Error when importing package in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, package, rpy2

I just installed R and Rstudio apart from anaconda, since it didn't launch after installing through anaconda. Now I can't import rpy2 anymore in my jupyter notebook as it takes forever, this is copied from the terminal when importing rpy2:

```
[I 11:49:33.918 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 690ca364-26ac-4a95-bce0-15f9ea605749

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x2e9e8, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: initMethodDispatch(where)
 2: fun(libname, pkgname)
 3: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 4: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 5: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 6: tryCatch(fun(libname, pkgname), error = identity)
 7: runHook(".onLoad", env, package.lib, package)
 8: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 9: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
10: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
11: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
12: tryCatch({    attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc    ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)}, error = function(e) {    P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e)))         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])    else ""    msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s",         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))    if (logical.return)         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)    else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)})
13: library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,     warn.conflicts = warn.conflicts, quietly = quietly, mask.ok = mask.ok,     exclude = exclude, include.only = include.only, attach.required = attach.required)
14: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
15: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
16: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
17: tryCatch(library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE,     logical.return = TRUE, warn.conflicts = warn.conflicts, quietly = quietly,     mask.ok = mask.ok, exclude = exclude, include.only = include.only,     attach.required = attach.required), error = function(e) e)
18: require(pkg, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE, character.only = TRUE)
19: .OptRequireMethods()

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: 
Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection:
 Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: 
Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: 
Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: 
Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: 
Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: 
Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection: Selection
```

The 'Selection:' keeps going on forever... What should I do?

Comment: Did you reinstall rpy2 after installing a new R ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that but it didn't work. What did work was reinstalling anaconda and use a conda environment for 'pip install rpy2'... Using 'conda install rpy2' implied a lot of errors and on top of that I had to install java and xquartz. Installing through pip in the base conda messed up several parts of my anaconda distribution, which I think caused the above problem. Therefore, I suggest people with a comparable problem to use environments.

edit: I still had to use an external version of R and Rstudio using homebrew

Comment: rpy2 should work well with environments (development is done using environments).  Anaconda seems to be involved in a lot of installation issues, and in the past rpy2 was always few versions behind in their package repository.